# d3 layout, d3 js event[type].add is not a function error

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I wanted to use 2 way d3 tree as per http://bl.ocks.org/kanesee/5d6c48bffd4ea31201fb

I have been using d3 js in my application before for different visualization , but it seems this tree also needs d3.layout.js.

When I included d3.layout.js , I am getting  event[type].add is not a function error.

Is there any particular reason for this error.
Any help would be appreciated , thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you share your code?

Comment: Hi , I have solved it b y removing all the same code from  D3.layout.js which was present in D3.js as well . Seems like only tree layout related code is required in my scenario.